# AN and extra mesh addon

Tags: python, animation-nodes

I treid but I see no way of adding addional images to this post so I'm giving up
this question is inspired by a post from wishmasteregel called "How to create explicit  (parametric) functions in animation node?. Answered by Omar Emara  using math nodes.
I followed along the setup and wondered if it were possible to achieve the same result by not using math nodes but a sccript node instread
Here is the result of one of Dupin Cyclids so far (AN 3D viewer).
[image]

Here is the node tree.

[image]

I was wondering if you could achieve with AN something equivalent to the output of the Extra Mesh Addon

[image]

Why bother at all if the Addon already gives back the result, but  I like the challenge, besides I'm ill at the moment an not fit for neccessary heavy learning.
So far I looked under Mesh Nodes but torus does not belong to the 
Generators
I've connected the output of the Invoke Subprogramm Loop with a Mesh Object Output node with a Torus as object but all I get in the 3D View is an ouput like the AN 3D viewr just with unconnected vertices

I've tried looking at the tutorials to AN nodes, but found no answers, so I came to ask here.
At the moment the output of the script node is a x-, y- and z-list which I combine to a Vector List.
Is ther a way to flesh out the unconected vertices with edges and faces?
thanks in advance
All I need is a good starting point

Comment: What about using a spline with control points in the center of each ring of the output vectors, and then controlling its size depending on the radius of each ring ? Would you mind sharing your blend file, or at least the script your are using ?

Comment: Hi Gregorius,I apologize for not answering earlier - I was on the lookout for answers and forgot all about comments.